# How to detect if at least one list item has a class name

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to detect if at least one of the `li.tst` list items has a `.count` class and then display `.msg` division ?

```
<ul>
    <li class="tst 1 na">li</li>
    <li class="tst 2 na">li</li>
    <li class="tst 3 count">li count</li>
    <li class="tst 4 na">li</li>
</ul>
<div class="msg" style="display: none;">has count</div>
```

**Examples:**

Has count: true:

```
<ul>
    <li class="tst 1 count">li</li>
    <li class="tst 2 na">li</li>
    <li class="tst 3 count">li count</li>
    <li class="tst 4 na">li</li>
</ul>
<div class="msg" style="display: block;">has count</div>
```

Has count: false:

```
<ul>
    <li class="tst 1 na">li</li>
    <li class="tst 2 na">li</li>
    <li class="tst 3 na">li count</li>
    <li class="tst 4 na">li</li>
</ul>
<div class="msg" style="display: none;">has count</div>
```

Anyway to do that with Jquery ? I hope this I am not duplicating.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get all `li` that has class `count`, like so

```
var $msg = $('.msg');

if ($('ul > li.count').length) {
    $msg.show();    
} else {
    $msg.hide();  
}
```

and then check `.length`

[`Example`](http://jsfiddle.net/gyfL75ox/2/)

Comment: Thank you Alexander !! accepting your answer when allowed.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `.filter` for this task

```
 var count = $('ul li').filter(function(){return $(this).hasClass("count");});
 if(count.length)
    $('.msg').show();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the length of a collection to see if any elements where found

```
if ( $('.count').length > 0 ) {
    $('.msg').show();
}
```

or if you want to toggle

```
$('.msg').toggle( $('.count').length > 0 );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot adeneo ! appreciated :)